# Slide Down Content of Multiple Pages

Tags: php, css, html

I'm trying to make a slide down menu according to this article:
http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

The example above shows how to make slide-down page on a single page.

Now, for example I have multiple pages like so:

> index.php
>
> about.php
>
> contact.php

The question: Is it possible to make a slide down content over the multiple / three pages above?

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the site function the way you want you will need to take the content from each of those pages and put them as sections on the index.php page. Each section will have a unique ID like so:

```
<div class="section about" id="about">
  -- about.php content goes here
</div>
<div class="section contact" id="contact">
 -- contact.php page content goes here --
</div>
```

Then in your jquery put the following code:

```
// Jump to target function
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });

    });
```

In your navigation you will put the link as

```
<a href="#about">About Us</a>
```

and you will see the scrolling effect when you click that link to take you to that section of the page.